# Reading the hidden class-property of an Object but confused by the outputs

Tags: javascript

One can use the hidden class-property of an JavaScript-object to get specific information which object one is dealing with.
Exact explanation: http://javascript.info/tutorial/type-detection#class-to-differ-between-native-objects

I have played around with it and it works. But then I found something which I don't understand until now. Please have a look at the following code:

```
var r = new RegExp();

console.log(Math.toString.call(r));
// Successful. Returns: '[object RegExp]'

console.log(Object.toString.call(r));
// Fails.
//   'TypeError: Function.prototype.toString called on incompatible object'
```

Why isn't it possible to use the toString-method of Object? It works with Math-, RegExp-Object or any self-constructed object.

All objects inherit toString from Object. So it seemed to me logical to use it. But as you can see / try it fails. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All objects inherit toString from Object.

Correct, but they inherit `toString` from the prototype.

So they inherit:

```
Object.prototype.toString
```

which you can use print regular expressions

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(/^\d+/)
```

---

But why can you use `Math.toString.call(r)` but not `Object.toString.call(r)`?

You are using a method that only exists because the *`Object` class* itself is also an `Object`, which inherits from the *`Object` class* again which is an `Object` again and inherits...

You get the point? There is no way to resolve the correct `Object.toString`. (So it seems like most browsers simply throw an exception when it is called.)

<sub>I'm getting headache...</sub>

Comment: var r = new RegExp();

console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(r));
// Result: "[object RegExp]" => Works! Thanks a lot. :-)